# Logic circuit simulation

Tags: java, logic, simulation

I have made a small program that computes logic circuits' truth tables. In the representation I have chosen (out of ignorance, I have no schooling on the subject), I use a Circuit class, and a Connector class to represent "circuits" (including basic gates such as NOT, OR...) and wiring.

A Factory class is used to "solder the pins and wires" with statements looking like this

```
factory.addCircuit("OR0", CircuitFactory.OR);
factory.addConnector("N0OUT", "NOT0", 0, "AND1", 1);
```

When the circuit is complete

```
factory.createTruthTable();
```

computes the circuit's truth table.
Inputing the truth tables for OR NOT and AND, the code has chained the creation of XOR, 1/2 ADDER, ADDER and 4-bit ADDER, reusing the previous step's truth table at each step.

It's all very fine and dandy for an afternoon's work, but it will obviously break on loops (as an example, flip-flops). Does anyone know of a convenient way to represent a logic circuit with loops? Ideal would be if it could be represented with a table, maybe a table with previous states, new states and delays.

Pointing me to litterature describing such a representation would also be fine. One hour of internet searching brought only a PhD paper, a little over my understanding.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Does it have to be Java? If you can handle OCaml then see http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~jrh13/atp/ select prop.ml and look at print_truthtable and the examples using it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any loop must contain at least one node with "state", of which the flip-flop (or register) is the fundamental building block.  An effective approach is to split all stateful nodes into two nodes; one acting as a data *source*, the other as a data *sink*.  So you now have no loops.<sup>*</sup>

To simulate, on every clock cycle,<sup>**</sup> you propagate your data values from sources to sinks in a feedforward fashion.  Then you update your stateful sources (from their corresponding sinks), ready for the next cycle.

---

<sub>* If you still have loops at this point, then you have an invalid circuit graph.</sub>

<sub>** I'm assuming you want to simulate *synchronous* logic, i.e. you have a clock, and state only updates on clock edges.  If you want to simulate *asynchronous* logic, then things get trickier, as you need to start modelling propagation delays and so on.</sub>

Comment: Interestingly, real-world [D flip-flops](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flip-flop_(electronics)#Edge-triggered_dynamic_D_storage_element) do this internally. They are made of two transparent latches in sequence. When the clock is low, the first latch is transparent while the second holds its old value, and when the clock goes high, the first latch holds its value while the second becomes transparent.

Comment: @WillWare: Yes, absolutely.  It's basically two different ways of looking at the same problem.  Though node splitting has potential advantages from a graph-theory point of view, in that it gives you well-defined "starting points" when figuring out how to traverse the graph (you can't do a [topological sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sort) on a cyclic graph).

Comment: I was tweaking the content of my comment above and hit the time limit. In the previous version, I mentioned that the nomenclature I've used (just how my brain works) is currentValue and nextValue, where on each clock edge all currentValues are replaced by their nextValues, and between clock edges you are computing the nextValues as a function of the currentValues.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanations. I'm a little tipsy (a shandy is all it takes for me, I'm afraid), therefore I'll read it thoroughly tomorrow.

Comment: Sorry I didn't answer earlier. I have since then discovered finite automata. Is any logic circuit a finite automata? Is any logic circuit describable by a state transition table? I believe these are the questions I would have asked, if I had heard of this earlier.

Comment: @pouzzler: Any synchronous logic circuit; yes.  Because ultimately it consists of state variables, and combinatorial logic that updates them.

Comment: When I was in school, they told us about a non-clocked form of asynchronous logic where all the transitions are single bit flips, so you get a cascade of bit flips to slide around in state space at dizzying speeds, each "state" lasting one propagation delay. As you might imagine, designing in this style is a bit of a nightmare and you'd want to simulate your design under all possible conditions of temperature, tolerances, and whatever else. Look up "Asynchronous circuit" on Wikipedia. I'm surprised there's an article, I've never heard of a serious design done this way intentionally.